# Unity detecting GameObjects behind Camera

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, 3d, camera

I have a map gameobject, that has 8x8 childs, set up in rows and columns. The hero can go circular on the edges, ie from [0,0] to [8,0]. That part works good, but you can't see where are you going on the edge, so I've set up a script, that will copy the tiles which are behind the camera to the sight of the camera.

```
for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++) {
    Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);
    if (child.position.z < Camera.current.transform.position.z) {
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0,0,8);
        child.transform.position += offset;
    }
}
```

the problem with this, is that the camera uses a follow script on the hero, so it has rotation as well. **How to edit the script above to move only the childs that are out of camera sight, and move them with the correct offset what is dependant on the direction?**
So on the following image, I'd like to move the tiles from red mark to the green mark. now it's 16 by 16, because it looks better :)

[image]

Comment: Can u please give some picture view r screenshot to know more about your problem.

Comment: added the pic. thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: Check this link... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html  ... you may get idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Renderer.isVisible`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html) method on these tiles renderers.

Comment: ahh, lovely :) much simpler than I expected :D